# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.cartif.database.Role#Project]

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am developing with Hibernate. So, when I want to load a eentity, I get an error like:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.cartif.database.Role#Project]
```

My hibernate mapping file is:

```
<hibernate-mapping> 
<class name="com.cartif.database.Role" table="Role">
    <id column="name" name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property column="permission" generated="never" lazy="false" name="permission" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the call on session is:

```
(Role)DatabaseManager.loadObject(Role.class, loadUser(login).getRole())

public static Object loadObject(Class o, String id){
    if(session == null) createSession();
    return session.get(o, id);
}
```

I have checked the package and the name of table, but they are OK! What could the problem be?

Thanks!

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the user which I have connected does not have permission. I add grants to user in database and it runs!